# How do different National Labs "compare?"

Tags: career-path

I am looking at offers from multiple national labs and wanted to know broadly how each compared. Are there "more prestigious" national labs than others (similar to universities)? Are some known for being "better to work for" or "worse to work for"?

P.S. I am referring to USA Department of Energy Labs.

Comment: In which country?  Which agency?  My best guess is that you're talking about US DOE labs, but it's just a guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "shopping question" asking for a comparison of particular institutions.

Comment: it is about DOE labs

Answer (score 2):

While it's off-topic to discuss "rankings" of different work environments, since those are inherently opinion-based, I can comment on my own experiences and observations having worked in the US DOE lab system for several years.

My main recommendation is not to look at the "prestige" factor of the different labs; instead, you should take a closer look at the individual positions you have been offered, and more importantly at where the funding for those positions comes from. If you are being hired into a well-funded, stable project, your experience is going to be very different from someone in a "soft money" position who will be responsible for making sure she has enough projects to bring in her salary. In general, my experience is that people tend to be happier in the former type of positions than the latter type.

However, there is a downside to the former type of position: you may find yourself in the position that you may not be able to move out of that position later on if you want to switch or at least transition out of that path. (Since you're already in a well-funded position, why should you get any soft money that other people need more?)